# AWS S3 iOS SDK: How to resume upload after connection is interrupted?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is my code to accomplish the upload task:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "12.jpeg")
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.99)
let path = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("\(imageData!).jpeg")

fileManager.createFile(atPath: path as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)

let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

uploadRequest?.bucket = "testrawdata"
uploadRequest?.key = "test/loodfd.jpeg"
uploadRequest?.contentType = "image/jpeg"
uploadRequest?.body = fileUrl as URL!
uploadRequest?.serverSideEncryption = AWSS3ServerSideEncryption.awsKms
uploadRequest?.uploadProgress = { (bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend) -> Void in
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

        print("bytes sent \(bytesSent), total bytes sent \(totalBytesSent), of total \(totalBytesExpectedToSend)")

    })
}


transferManager?.upload(uploadRequest).continue(with: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), withSuccessBlock: { (taskk: AWSTask) -> Any? in
    if taskk.error != nil {
        // Error.
    } else {
        // Do something with your result.
    }
    return nil
})
}
```

I know I don't need to apply it to image, but this is just an example, by default I'm going to send files like 100mb.

When I put my phone into airplane mode during the transfer then turn the network on again, it does not finish the upload task.

Docs are not saying explicitly what should I do to resume interrupted task.

Here is what I tried:

I put initialization of request and manager into viewDidLoad() to assure I'm not creating another request

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var uploadRequest:AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest!
var transferManager: AWSS3TransferManager!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
    transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()

}
```

and tried to call

```
    func resumeTransfer() {

   transferManager?.resumeAll(nil)

}
```

But it does not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked out http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html#create-the-s3-transfermanager-client ?

Comment: @WestonE  I did and failed to find the answer to my question

Comment: Are you having problems with resume for individual files?

From the dev guide:
-----
To resume a transfer, call upload or download, as appropriate, and pass in the paused request:

[transferManager upload:uploadRequest];
[transferManager download:downloadRequest];
------

Comment: My question is about resuming interrupted task - to make it start where it left off before interruption. What I get i starting over from the beginning

Comment: The Transfer Manager itself does not monitor the network. If you want to detect when the network is lost and pause, then you will need to do that yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that Transfer Utility is the right tool to accomplish this task

```
func uploadData(data: NSData) {

    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
    expression.progressBlock = progressBlock

    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()

    transferUtility.uploadData(
        data as Data,
        bucket: "test",
        key: "test/test.jpeg",
        contentType: "image/jpeg",
        expression: expression,
        completionHander: completionHandler).continue(successBlock: { (task) -> AnyObject! in
            if let error = task.error {
                NSLog("Error: %@",error.localizedDescription);

            }
            if let exception = task.exception {
                NSLog("Exception: %@",exception.description);

            }
            if let _ = task.result {

                NSLog("Upload Starting!")
                // Do something with uploadTask.
            }

            return nil;
        })
}
```

This way all upload stuff happens in the background, I don't have to worry about app being killed by the iOS, about networks problem etc.

One can even specify

```
configuration?.allowsCellularAccess = false
```

in `AWSServiceConfiguration`

to resume the task only when wifi is available.

Comment: Did you find that TransferUtility would resume a large upload from where it left off if there was a network interruption?  Because from my testing and what I have read it just restarts from the beginning.

Comment: Transfer utility doesn't work for files that will take over 50 minutes to transfer